# Running regini from python

Tags: python, windows, permissions, registry

The following is all using python as the scripting language. Ok I made a txt file and am attempting to use regini to make changes to two registry key permissions from a python script that is going to automate an install process for some techs at my office. The script is called perm.txt. Here is what I have tried.

```
pr = subprocess.Popen("regini perm.txt", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

os.system("regini perm.txt")

pr = subprocess.Popen("reg.bat", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

os.system("reg.bat")
```

the reg.bat file contains

```
@echo off
regini perm.txt
```

perm.txt contains
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon [1 5 7 17]

when I run the reg.bat file myself by clicking on it or calling it in command prompt the permissions change perfectly, same thing happens when I run "regini perm.txt". However when I run any of these through python the permissions don't change. I don't get any errors it just does not affect the permissions. I shouldn't get any errors because I know the command regini and the batch file both work perfectly when I run them manually. I am pulling at straws here and have tried tons a different ways to make this work, if anyone knows of a better way to change the permissions through python or make these commands work please let me know. I have looked at winreg but cannot seem to find a way to use it to change registry permissions.

Comment: Possibly you're using 32-bit Python, so it runs 32-bit regini and registry access gets redirected to `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node`. In that case you can explicitly run the 64-bit version instead. Use `output = subprocess.check_output(r'%s\Sysnative\regini.exe perm.txt' % os.environ['SystemRoot'], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)`. Don't use `shell=True`.